# Why doesn't my intellij idea maven project have a src directory?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, ide

I 'm using intellij idea 15 community to build a maven project and I chose the `maven-archetype-j2ee-simple` archetype.
[image]

The version of the maven I used was `Bundled(Maven 2)`.
[image]

However, I didn't find any directories like `src` and I didn't know where to write my java code. What's wrong with it?[image]

My working environment is Ubuntu 15.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it does. you just need to allow maven to import changes. Your last screen shot pretty much says it all.

I just created one with archetype-je22-simple and it includes everything as starter project:[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check

1. your maven path is set correctly
   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/maven_environment_setup.htm
2. run mvn --version and check if your maven is pointing to write jdk as well
3. IF these two things set correctly while creating project " archetype" list show show . if it is still not showing that means there is a problem in your setup and maven will still create empty maven config

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

1.Open IntelliJ IDEA and close any existing project.

2.From the Welcome screen, click Import Project.

3.open the `pom.xml` shows src.

[reference link.](https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.6.x/java/IntellijMaven.html)